# Why I am getting an error of "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory "

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I am getting an error message of **Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.**

I have used the cleanUp in useState but still I am getting error.

Here is the code:

```
    let isComponentMounted = useRef(false);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    isComponentMounted.current = true;
    setLoading(true);

    if(isComponentMounted){
      async function  fetchData(){
        const data = await fetch(`/data`) 
        const res = await data.json();
        setLoading(false);
        return res
      }
    
      fetchData().then((response)=>{
        setMovie(response.data.movies[Math.floor(Math.random()*response.data.movies.length-1)])
      })
    }


    return()=>{isComponentMounted.current = false; setMovie()}
  },[])
```

I am new to react it would be really helpful

Comment: Check if component is still mounted before calling `setMovie`

Comment: Why do you want to set state of a component which will unmount?

Comment: @TusharShahi I was trying to clear the state as I thought it would free the memory. Previously, I am tried with setState at cleanUp but still received the same error msg

Comment: The component is unmounted itself. I don't think you need to worry about its state. The cleanup should be fore external resources and timers.

Comment: @TusharShahi okay,But how to get rid of the error message of resource ?

Comment: try removing `setMovie()` form return `callback`.

Comment: anyway you have to remove `setMovie()` and if that didn't help - see this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53711492/12541413

Comment: Remove both the statements from you return if you do not need them. Remove setMovie() to get rid of warning.